# Generating example IDs in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec2

I need help figuring out how to generate a unique identifier for each example in my rspec tests. What do I change for the below code to work?

```
describe 'Verify that my server' do

    @x = 1

    it "does something " + @x.to_s do
        2.should==2
    end

    it "does something else " + @x.to_s do
        2.should==2
    end

    after(:each) do
        @x+=1
    end
end
```

Comment: Formatted your ruby code for stackoverflow ;)  Handy-tip, paste your code into your question, then select it and press ctrl + K (or CMD + k on Mac OS)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ffaker](https://github.com/EmmanuelOga/ffaker) for generating random values in tests.  It can generate real-looking random data, like e-mail addresses, IP addresses, phone numbers, people's names etc, but it also has basic methods for generating random strings of letters and numbers.

```
Faker.numerify("###-###-###")
# => 123-456-789
```

Alternatively you can use stdlib's [SecureRandom](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/securerandom/1.9.2/SecureRandom).

Answer (score -1):

Each example in your Rspec should complete a sentence, a sentence you usually start in a `describe` block encapsulating related tests.

I took this from one of my own specs:

```
describe Redis::BigHash do
  before :each do
    @hash = Redis::BigHash.new
    @hash[:foo] = "bar"
    @hash[:yin] = "yang"
  end

  describe "#[]" do
    it "should read an existing value" do
      @hash[:foo].should == "bar"
    end
    it "should get nil for a value that doesn't exist" do
      @hash[:bad_key].should be_nil
    end
    it "should allow lookup of multiple keys, returning an array" do
      @hash[:foo, :yin, :bad_key].should == ["bar", "yang", nil]
    end
  end
end
```

You end up with sentences like:

- `Redis::BigHash#[]` should read an existing value.
- `Redis::BigHash#[]` should get nil for a value that doesn't exist.
- `Redis::BigHash#[]` should allow lookup of multiple keys, returning an array.

Just simple English sentences that describe the behavior you want.

Comment: Friendly nit-pick, IMHO the messages read better if you omit "should", e.g.: `Redis::BigHash#[] reads an existing value`.  I want to know the specified behaviour, not the hypothetical behaviour :)

Comment: very true but very much not answering the question